# Can I create a Task to upload my library?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I'm using Android Studio 1.1, with this one I create a library for another project.
I would like to know if I can upload my library. I want to get it with gradle like the others dependencies :

> ```
> compile 'com.mylib.MyLib:V1:1.0'
> ```

It's possible?

My project isn't a maven project.

Thanks for your attention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually there are existing gradle plugins for publishing your artifacts.
You can read about these plugins and tasks in gradle user guide in the following chapters:

- [8.6 Publishing Artifacts](http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/artifact_dependencies_tutorial.html#N10669) - a basic scenario
- [52. Publishing artifacts](http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/artifact_management.html) - the original publishing mechanism available in Gradle 1.0
- [65. Ivy Publishing (new)](http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/publishing_ivy.html) and [66. Maven Publishing (new)](http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/publishing_maven.html) - the new publishing plugins

Comment: Thanks for the help! To use Maven I have to change the build.gradle (project), the repositories is defined "jcenter()"by default. I have to change to maven or isn't the same thing?